Ports open in UFW but still shut to the outside world
I'm running Ubuntu 24.04.  I'm having trouble communicating with RoundcubeMail on port 443 (HTTPS) with UFW inactive, so I tried activating it and setting the ports to 'open'.
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
587                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
993                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
25                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
143                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
587 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
993 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
25 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
143 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

but from a different machine I get:
Starting Nmap 7.95 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2024-11-24 17:44 GMT
Nmap scan report for example.com (xx.xx.xx.xx)
Host is up (0.011s latency).
Not shown: 991 filtered tcp ports (no-response)
PORT    STATE  SERVICE
22/tcp  open   ssh
25/tcp  closed smtp
80/tcp  closed http
110/tcp closed pop3
443/tcp closed https
465/tcp closed smtps
587/tcp closed submission
993/tcp closed imaps
995/tcp closed pop3s

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 18.42 seconds

Can anyone throw any light on this behaviour?

What is the status of the service on port 443? Is there a router or firewall between the server and the internet that could be blocking?

This question is similar to: Ports closing to incoming traffic. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
